# Grails : Retrieve all latest children records

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am new to Grails , I have some issue as stated below.

I have 2 domain classes : Parent and Child. I am storing arrays of arrays into database.

Parent class is :

```
class Parent{
    static hasMany = [child: Child]
}
```

Child class is :

```
class Child {

    String time
    String record
    String value
    static belongsTo= [parent: Parent]

    static constraints = {
        time(blank: false)
        record(blank: false)
        belongsTo(blank: false)
    }
}
```

Now my requirement is :

I need to retrieve the child's latest records that contain multiple rows in the database with unique parent id.
e.g : Parent's latest id is 7.
Child table contains nearly 10 records on parent id 7. I want to retrieve all these 10 records with the reference of the parent id(7).

Please some one help to write a code/query .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gorm` is a greate `ORM` you could use following:

```
def parent = Parent.get(7)
def childList = Child.findAllByParent(parent);
```

read [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html), it'll help you to understand `gorm` better.